# No such file or directory when I try to cd to a directory with two words in the name

Tags: command-line, directory, cd-command

I  am trying to untar a file and to do so, I have to go to the directory in terminal.

[image: Screeshot]

So as in the screenshot above, My downloads are stored in Downloads/Chrome Downloads. But when I type the command,

```
cd Downloads/Chrome Downloads
cd home/Downloads/Chrome Downloads
cd home/Downloads/Chrome-Downloads
cd home/Downloads/Chrome_Downloads
cd Downloads > cd Chrome Downloads
```

It says NO such file or directory

Please tell me the correct command to change directory of a folder with two words as the file name (`Chrome Downloads`).

Comment: Try: `cd Downloads/Chrome\ Downloads` The problem is the space, Tab completion is another option or the use of double apostrophes...

Comment: You may find these questions helpful: [How do I change the current working directory to the Downloads directory?](https://askubuntu.com/q/262674), [How to write the path of a folder with space in it's name?](https://askubuntu.com/q/530578), [When to use a preceding slash in path names? (e.g. for the 'cd' command)](https://askubuntu.com/q/607413), [Home folder in `root` and not in `home`… I'm confused!](https://askubuntu.com/q/196204). Also the UsingTheTerminal wiki page, which contains [File & Directory Commands](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#File_.26_Directory_Commands).

Comment: summary: the path to the Downloads directory can be written `/home/$USER/Downloads`, `$HOME/Downloads` or `~/Downloads`, but if you open a terminal you are usually in your $HOME so you can `cd Downloads`. The easiest way to type a filename with spaces is often to type the first few letters and then press tab. If you need to type spaces, put a `\ ` before each one.

Answer (score 0):

You can change to the directory with space by putting \ before the space which in your case is chrome\ download. You can use tab completion for same.